# Listar Elementos da Relação has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

estou criando uma aplicação e realizei uma relação has_many :through em meu modelo. Até ai tudo bem, funcionou sem problemas, salva, edita e exclui. O problema é que eu gostaria de listar todos os elementos que estão na terceira tabela desta relação na view. Estou a horas procurando e tentando fazer mais sem sucesso.

Este é meu modelo:

```
class Imovel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :caracteristica_imovels, inverse_of: :imovel
  has_many :caracteristicas, through: :caracteristica_imovels, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :caracteristica_imovels, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Na view estou tentando imprimir todas as características do imóvel, porém, sem sucesso. Tentei desta forma:

```
<% @imovel.caracteristicas.each do %>
      <%= @imovel.caracteristicas.nome %>
  <%end%>
```

Desta também:

```
<%= @imovel = Imovel.joins(:caracteristica_imovel).includes(:nome)%>
```

Desta segunda forma erros não acontecem mas apenas fica impresso: 
`#<Imovel::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe915b469e0>`

Como posso fazer esta listagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenta desta forma:

```
<% @imovel.caracteristicas.each do |item| %>
   <dd><%= item.nome %> </dd> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Você salvou o dia meu amigo. Ficando assim: <% @imovel.caracteristicas.each do |item| %>
   <dd><%=  item.nome %> </dd>
  <% end %> funcionou! Muito obrigado.